# error in using shinyserver

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have run shinyAPP in server, some APP doesn't work and error message show as picture, I don't know how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: error message"Diagnostic information has been dumped to the JavaScript error console."

Comment: Locate the error in your web browser, 
For Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console 
For Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: If we can't reproduce the error, we can't help.

Comment: I don't know how to insert image,haha~. can u visit http://xiukun.wang:3838/gps/ ??

Comment: We can see screenshot error image on the link in your post, we need your code and maybe data to reproduce the same error.

Comment: `library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$values <- renderLeaflet({
     inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    dat <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
     quote=input$quote)
     
 p <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addCircles(lng=dat$longitude, lat=dat$latitude , popup = dat$member_id) 
  })
})`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no dplyr package installed in the library used by the R process which your shiny server is using.

from browser console:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:56037
Warning: Error in library: there is no package called ‘dplyr’
Stack trace (innermost first):
    38: library
     1: runApp
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

Ensure that you have the package installed in the library folder used by shiny server. 
E.g. in my case I have separate R used by RStudio so that development is separated from live app.

My library sits in `usr//lib64//R//library` therefore in linux i will run R as superuser `sudo R` and then `install.packages("dplyr", lib="usr//lib64//R//library//")`

Comment: I have installed dplyr package,but it doesn't work still.

Comment: The error is definitely due to missing library, i have tested on my server and adding something like `library(aareshape2)` will return same error and cause the app to fail. Which OS are you using on your server? My best guess is we need to check for installed packages, which library path they are installed in and if the user running the shiny app has permissions to read given folder/files

Comment: haha, it is diffcult to me. I don't know if shiny App has permissions. it is first  time to run APP in ubutun shinyserver(I can run shiny default example).do you have good idea?(my package lib is "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/library")